# Program Continues to Crash [Project Euler #21]

Tags: c++

I'm running this program in C++ to find the sum of all amicable numbers below 10000. Yes, this is my program for [Project Euler question 21](http://projecteuler.net/problem=21). I already know that the algorithm is not the most efficient one, and the reason I'm posting this has nothing to do with the efficiency of the program.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int sum = 0;
  int d[10000];
  for (int i = 0; i <= 9999; i++)
    d[i] = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i <= 9999; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j < i; j++)
      if (i%j == 0)
        d[i] += j;
  for (int i = 1; i <= 9999; i++)
    if (d[d[i]] == i)
      sum += i;
  cout << sum/2;
}
```

The error seems to occur in the last `for` loop - I commented it out and everything runs fine (other than, of course, giving the obviously wrong result of 0). The error message I get is this

[image]

followed by this:

```
----jGRASP exec: C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Project Euler\problem.exe

----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is -1073741819.
----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

And now for the obvious question - WHY is this error happening?

Comment: It's just poor practice to have all of these nested loops and conditionals without delimiting them with braces! Also, your function doesn't return a value, which may also be the problem. Write your code properly, following K&R or some other good reference, and see if your problem persists.

Comment: Now that you've fixed your bounds checking, the problem statement says "Evaluate the sum of all the amicable numbers under 10000".  Why are you dividing your sum by 2?  Also, you're not checking `d[i] != i`.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
 if ( d[d[i]] == i)
```

is going access `d` beyond the valid range of indices since `d[i]` can be greater than `9999`.
Change it to:

```
 if ( d[i] <= 9999 && d[d[i]] == i)
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. My answer's apparently wrong, but I'll try and figure out this issue on my own.

Answer (score 0):

If d[i] ever gets a value greater than 10000, then d[d[i]] will be a reference outside the 10000 integers you've allocated.  That'll cause an error.